# How can i round a value in django template without using the filter

Tags: django-templates

Is there any way that I can do some [python math](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html) function in django template. Actually I need to round a variable value and I want to achieve this without using the filters.

For example like `{{math.round(total)}}`.

Comment: Is there any problem in using the [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) filter?

Comment: ok..but how can i perform  math functions? is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is the function you want to perform? Explain clearly

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) to round of the value in django template.

```
{{ total|floatformat }}
```

If you want to perform more mathematical operations, you can try [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters). Or you could write your [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and perform the operations in that template tag.

Answer (score 23):

@arulmr gave the best way to fixed it, In my case I also needed include

```
{{ total|floatformat:0 }}
```

In order to round the value with zero decimal places, and

```
{{ total|floatformat:1 }}
```

To define the decimal places