# Rounding down a number to nearest 1000 in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I want to round a number down to the nearest 1000 in Django template.

Something like

```
{{ 123456 | round(1000) }}

123000
```

Is there a built-in way to do this in Django or should I just write a custom template tag?

Comment: I can not immediately find one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185351/how-can-i-round-a-value-in-django-template-without-using-the-filter

Comment: @Rakesh: this will only round to the *nearest* integer (given the parameter is `0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not find such function in the [*Built-in template tags and filters* in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/). The closest is [**`floatformat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) but then we can only round to an integer (not on thousands, etc.).

Writing a custom template filter is however not that hard:

```
# app/templatetags/rounding.py

from django import template
from decimal import Decimal

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def round_down(value, size=1):
    size = Decimal(size)
    return (Decimal(value)//size) * size
```

or if you plan to only use integers:

```
@register.filter
def round_down(value, size=1):
    size = int(size)
    return (value//size) * size
```

Then we can format it with:

```
{% load rounding %}

{{ 123456|round_down:"1000" }}
```

This then generates:

```
>>> t = """{% load rounding %}{{ 123456|round_down:"1000" }}"""
>>> Template(t).render(Context())
'123000'
```