# How do I display a rounded version of a number in my Django/Python template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, templates, rounding

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  In my template I have this

```
{{ round(articlestat.votes) }}
```

which results in teh error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(articlestat.votes)' from 'round(articlestat.votes)'
```

Is there a way to display a rounded version of my number without creating an additional @property method in the model?   It just seems like overkill to do a method every time I want the data formatted a little differently.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186153/9848469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) filter like:

```
{{ articlestat.votes|floatformat:"0" }}
```