# How to parse or round decimal point in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have a ML model that can produce a number of array which have lot of numbers after decimal point. I used joblib to extract model and used it on django to show my data. But the problem is I am not able to round up decimal point where I already used round(i,2)**[its not work]**. Is their any other solution which I can apply ?

**Here is the views.py**
[image]

**Here is the template- home.html**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

My intension is to **showing 4.38% instead of 4.387352524728998 %**
Please help me out, I am lost in the dark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i round a value in django template without using the filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185351/how-can-i-round-a-value-in-django-template-without-using-the-filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `floatformat` template filter

```
{{ i|floatformat:2 }}
```